# Python to .net web service Image created but corrupted

Tags: c#, python

I am sending an image and other parameters from python to a web service (.net) endpoint. While I convert it to byte and then write to disk, the image created can not be displayed... error is 'the image can not displayed because it contains error'. Here is my code in python...

```
def upload_form():
    header = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    params = {'imagefile':bx64, 'sacid':'3', 'astid':'188', 'docName':'abc4', 'docExtn':'png'}
    url='http://localhost:47176/snapshot.svc/DoUpload'
    selector =''

    try:
        _data = dumps(params)           
        req = request.Request(url)
        connection = http.client.HTTPConnection(req.host)
        connection.request ('POST', req.selector, _data, header)
        response = connection.getresponse()
        print('response = %s', response.read())
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error...', e)

bx64 = get_b64string('some png file name')

def get_b64string(file):
    ENCODING = 'utf-8'

    with open(file, 'rb') as open_file:
        return b64encode(open_file.read()).decode(ENCODING)
```

While at server side, endpoint code is...

```
    public string DoUpload(string imagefile, string sacid, string astid, string docName, string docExtn)
    {
        string m_fileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", docName, docExtn.Replace(".", ""));
        string m_host = string.Format("{0}/{1}", FTPUrl, sacid.ToString());

        try
        {
            byte[] imgbinaryarray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imagefile);
            if (UploadToFtp(imgbinaryarray, FTPUrl, Convert.ToInt32(sacid), Convert.ToInt32(astid), m_fileName)) return "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log and return error                
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return "File could not be processed, contact application support!";
    }
```

Edited:
I have modified the code to use 'requests' library in python and also the end point accordingly.

End Point:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string DoFileUpload(Stream fileContent)
    {
        string docName = "abc-"+DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        string m_fileName = string.Format("{0}.jpg",docName);

        string filePath = string.Format("C:\\Temp\\Upload\\{0}", m_fileName);
        try
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                fileContent.CopyTo(fs);
            }
            return "OK";        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Python Code:

```
        def upload_form3(fileToUpload):
        try:
            url = 'http://localhost:47176/snapshot.svc/DoFileUpload'
            files = {'fileContent':open(fileToUpload,'rb')}             
            r = requests.post(url, files=files)
            print(r.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print('upload_form3. Error...', e)
```

Still the file created is showing same error i.e. can not open file contains error.

Comment: Your code is not sufficient to understand your problem. An HTTP trace would also greatly help. You seem to encode your image as a JSON object, is that what the .NET side expects ? Also I suggest that you use the python `requests` lib to do the HTTP work, it would simplify your code greatly.

Comment: The problem is that end point receives the data in each parameters with correct data types however, image created from the string is somehow not correct and so I can not view it; `requests` is definitely good but data be still passed as json, isn't it?

Comment: I think I have located the issue. When I open the file in text mode, I see the following text... `--37449d2fb479404e892dbc2b46e05704
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileContent"; filename="site1.jpg"

‰PNG

   ` When I removed the texts upto **%** the error is gone.

Comment: Please note that this header information is the same as I have passed while doing post. So it seems that `requests` library makes it part of the **bytes** it created and it got written to the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Used like you are doing, requests will post a MIME multipart-encoded data, which your .Net side does not expect (it looks like it expects a simple stream, but I don't know .net enough to be sure).

Try with this python client code, it sends the file content as a simple stream:

```
def upload_form3(fileToUpload):
    try:
        url = 'http://localhost:47176/snapshot.svc/DoFileUpload'  
        with open(fileToUpload,'rb') as finput:
            r = requests.post(url, data=finput)
        print(r.text)
    except Exception as e:
        print('upload_form3. Error...', e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I am sorry that I came back late. The solution which I used is to read the stream in a memory stream, strip the initial bytes containing meta data / header information. Then write it to file and the image is correctly created.